# Clone radio buttons with CloneYa

Tags: jquery-cloneya

I'm cloning a form with the cloneya library, it seems to work correctly when cloning and deleting. The problem is that I have 3 radio buttons in my form, and when I clone them they are cloned with the same name. This causes that just one radio button can be selected in my entire form. I need to change the 3 group radio buttons name, so when I clone the form I can choose again one radio button without deselcting the previous one.
According to CloneYa documentation, when cloning a radio button I just need to change the name's attribute in array format:

```
(eg: <input type="radio" name="name[1]"/>)
```

but this doesn't work. I don't know if it's because I have a group of 3 radio buttons in my form.

I also try to change the name using

```
var count = 0;
var countDisplay = document.getElementById("count");
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function() {
        count++;
        countDisplay.innerHTML = count;
    });
});
$('.clone-wrapper').cloneya.find('input[type=radio]').attr('name','radioName' + count).end()
```

but here I'm having a problem with the count, when I click a radio button in the first form the count works correctly, but when I clone it and click on a radio button it does nothing. It's seems that in the clone sections it can't find input`[type=radio]`

The last thing I've tried is to look for the last character on the id in order to use that character to create a new name. For example, when I clone my form for the firts time all the elements, including the radio buttons have at the end of the id a "1", like this <id=radioButton1>. So, I'm trying to get the one and later on put it on the name using $("radioButton").css({name: "radioName" + currentID}) or something like that.
What I did this time was the following:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("input[type=radio]").on("click", function(){
        console.log("hola")
        $currentId=this.id.slice(-1);
        console.log($currentId)
    });
});
$('.clone-wrapper').cloneya()
```

I can't continue with this plan, because again in the fisrt form it works correctly, but when I clone it, it seems that there are no more ("input[type=radio]").

Any idea of how can I change the name of my radio buttons each time I clone it?

Thank you!